# Save Drawn Images PictureBox

Tags: c#, bitmap, draw, picturebox, drawtobitmap

My program allows the user to draw in a `PictureBox`.

I'm trying to save the `pictureBox1` as a `.jpg` file but this file is empty.

**My save button:**

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
this.pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, this.pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
bm.Save(String.Format("{0}.jpg", this.ID));
this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().Clear(Color.White);
```

**My draw event:**

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    drawNote.isDraw = true;
    drawNote.X = e.X;
    drawNote.Y = e.Y;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(drawNote.isDraw)
    {
        Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        G.DrawLine(drawNote.pen, drawNote.X, drawNote.Y, e.X, e.Y);

        drawNote.X = e.X;
        drawNote.Y = e.Y;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should create an empty `Bimap` set `pictureBox1.Image` by this bitmap then creat `graphics` from it, also you must store it in global variable to prevent recreat it.

Like this:

```
Graphics graphics = null;
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(drawNote.isDraw)
    {
        if (graphics == null) 
        {
          graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
          Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
          pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
          graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
          graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        }

        graphics.DrawLine(drawNote.pen, drawNote.X, drawNote.Y, e.X, e.Y);

        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Save();
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

        drawNote.X = e.X;
        drawNote.Y = e.Y;
    }
}
```

And you could do this by this simple code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(fileStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried but this file is empty.

Comment: @Ohy I change the answer and test it. It works. try it.

Comment: It works. Thank you! Thank you so much!!!